# The meaning of English sentences?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, translation

I have problem with English sentences, i can google the meaning of unknown words in it but when comes to the entire sentence meaning i still get confused.would you please express such sentence in another way that is easily acceptable?

> 1. that makes one want to put up disclaimers of all sorts...
> 2. anything that gets custom-tailored to you will not be high-grade prescription medication, but rather traditional stuff.

Comment: #1 is a relative clause, not a sentence. It refers back to some (unspecified) situation which for some (unspecified) reason makes you think it would be a good idea to restrict the scope of something (unspecified) that you said before, by adding exclusions and denying responsibility. But there's no connection between the two examples, so we cannot provide a coherent "answer" because it's **Unclear** what aspect of usage you're asking about.

Comment: The clause in 1. could also be written as "that makes one want to make all sorts of excuses...  But you really need to say more about what specifically is confusing you.

Comment: #1 could be a sentence, if "that" is interpreted as the subject.

Answer (score 1):

The context is important and thus, more information will be useful but I understand such agony we (the non-natives) have in our minds. :) I'll try to paraphrase it.

You just want to know the meaning. So, in the first sentence...

> to keep all the legal issues at bay, one must put all kinds of disclaimers. That makes...means you are forced/advised to do something. Here, it's putting all sorts of disclaimers

In the second sentence,

> Consider herbal medicines. They are *traditional stuff.* They work as per the nature of **your** health issue rather than correcting your problem in a general way. Customized or tailored means **fitting to your needs**.

I know herbs but if you come with cough and cold, I may give you the mix of some A, B, C herbs but if your friend comes, I'll look his [prakriti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prak%E1%B9%9Bti) and may decide upon giving him the mix of X, Y, Z herbs and **not** A, B, C.

So, it says... anything you get as tailored (specific to your body, your problem) won't be high-grade prescription (modern medicines, well researched, scientifically approved) but a traditional medicine/herbs that just work the way folk practitioners have been practicing. You may call 'dogmas' in holistic medicines!